# Rect attributes not seeming to be callable (colliderect)

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to create a little game in pygame. I'm currently working on collision and run into an error.

Full code here, https://pastebin.com/26WKbKzw

Collision Code in main loop:

```py
colliding = mcharacter.hitbox.colliderect(energy.hitbox)

    if colliding:
        print("It worked.")

    redrawGameWindow()
```

Class Code:

```py
class tardigrade(object):
    def __init__(self, name, height, width):
        self.name = name
        self.x = 500
        self.y = 300
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.velocity = random.randint(5,7)
        self.hp = random.randint(35,50)
        self.hunger = 0
        self.size = random.uniform(0.3,0.7)
        self.hitbox = pygame.Rect(self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height)

    def draw(self, win):
        win.blit(self.name, (self.x, self.y))
        self.hitbox = (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height)
        pygame.draw.rect(win, (0, 0, 255), self.hitbox,2)
```

The hitbox actually works, but after I declare it in my class and call it in my code I get this error. "AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'colliderect'". The collision even works and I added a print statement in the if collision statement that actually runs. From my understanding it wants me to call a certain item from the tuple but the tuple is supposed to be a pygame rect that represents a hitbox, requiring all four points on the window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining your tartigrade's `self.hitbox` as two separate things.

Here, in `__init__` it is defined properly as a Rect:

```
self.hitbox = pygame.Rect(self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height)
```

Here in draw it is replaced by a length 4 tuple:

```
self.hitbox = (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height)
```

You should rename one of these variables.